# NodeJS and Express: Add auth middleware to static path

Tags: node.js, express, stormpath

I have a node app running express as the web app framework and I use Stormpath for authentication.

Storm path gives the ability to protect a route with several middlewares,
for example:

```
router.get('/user_data_api', stormpath.apiAuthenticationRequired, function(req, res) {
        res.send('hello you are authenticated!");
     });
});
```

What I want to do is to add authenticationRequired as a middleware to the static definition of express:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This could be achieved by adding a route to the static assets, so if I have a file ./public/index.html I can set the route like this:

```
app.use('/secured-assets', 
               stormpath.auth_fn, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

But then the file will be in

> www.mydomain.com/secured-assets/index.html

And I want it in

> www.mydomain.com/index.html

Help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do just:

```
app.use(stormpath.auth_fn, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

It'll add `stormpath.auth_fn` and `express.static(__dirname + '/public')` middlewares to the `/` path and, hence, will protect every route.

Comment: ...what is the same as invoking `app.use()` twice, but with a single argument. More code, but more legibility.

Comment: And, if the OP goes this way, it'll protect every route, what wasn't specified in the question. Maybe it's worth note this in the answer.

Comment: @gustavohenke Yeah, it's the same as use `app.use()` twice. IMHO it's a matter of taste, not more legibility.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with Express ^4.13.4 and Stormpath ^3.1.2

```
app.use(stormpath.loginRequired, express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```